# Calculation of unity level (0dB) after gained VCA

Tags: dac, gain, calculation, voltage-controlled-amplifier

Basically I'm controlling a VCA (AS2164) with my Arduino through a 10 bit DAC. All is working well. The VCA output is then gained x 3.3 though an op amp, which in my calculator gives a 10dB boost.

The VCA by itself goes from -100db to 0dB by a logarithmic scale.

When the DAC is at 0 theres no atennuation (0dB). When the DAC is at 4095 (10 bit) there is full attenuation (-100dB).

What DAC value or fraction of the 10bit should I send to the VCA to get unity gain? By unity I mean 0dB level change from the input signal.

Does gaining the output by 10 db mean that the final level span goes from -90 to +10dB?
My own calculation would then be a tenth of the DAC value:

unityDACvalue =  int(0.1*4095) = 410;

Or do I miss something here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get total gain in dB you add gains of each stage together, so if the VCA goes from -100 dB to 0 dB and you have an amplifier with a gain of +10 dB after it the range will be -90 dB to +10 dB.

If you want a total of 0 dB gain you need to set the DAC so the VCA gain cancels the amplifier gain, so you need whatever DAC value gives the VCA a gain of -10dB. You could determine this mathematically if you know the equation for the VCA gain, or you could determine it experimentally by putting a signal with a known level in and adjusting the DAC until the output level is the same.

Also note that a gain of 3.3 in dB is
$$
20\cdot log_{10}(3.3\mathbin{/}1) = 10.37~dB
$$
If you want it to be closer to 10 dB your gain needs to be
$$
10^{(10~dB\mathbin{/}20)} = 3.1623
$$
You could add a trimmer to set it if precision matters.

Comment: Thanks @GodJihyo . That got me some of the way. 
To determin the point of 0dB mathematically is what I'm mosly unsure of. 

I can't really find any equation for the AS2164 VCA in the datasheet. Only that it attennuates 1 dB per 33mV of control voltage.  Noted as –33 mV/ dB - which seems pretty linear to me as far as control. My DAC Sends between 0 and 3.3 V which is 0 to -100dB

I guess I am mostly confused to know that the VCA has a logarithmic scale. But does that just mean the dB scale is logaritmic, but the control of attennuation V/dB is pretty linear?

Comment: So lets say i amplify the signal by 10.37 dB. That lifts my -100 dB attenuation span into  -89.63 to 10.37dB. 

Reaching 0 dB i would have to attenuate with 10.37/100 of maximum attenuation? 10.37/100 =  0.1037. 

I then need 0.1037 of the 3.3 V og full control voltage.  
Therefore I send 0.1037 * 4095 to the DAC. 

Correct me if I'm wrong :)

It seem ok from the level I hear, but as you mention i shoud try to make a bypass switch to detemin if my 0 dB unity is equal to the bypassed level.

Comment: @JesperKragh There's your formula, attn = -33mV/dB. If you need -10.37dB then that's -10.37dB * -33mV/dB, the dB terms cancel and you have -10.37 * 0.33mV = 0.34221V, that's your control voltage.  So 0.34221/(3.3/4095) = 424.6 which works out the same as your result (two ways to get to the same answer). Set the DAC to 425 and I think it should be good.